# dynamically generated pass for pasbook

Tags: objective-c, passbook, passkit

I have an application that generates a barcode using a third party library. This barcode is not static and changes every 30 seconds or so from within the app.

I'm aware the proper way is to get a signed pkpass file from your server to supply to passbook, and use APN or some sort of trigger within the iOS app to acquire a new barcode. But...due to certain reasons...some of this is not viable at the moment...

So...

Ideally, I would like to be able to allow the user so that every time they select my pass, I'm able to supply them with the dynamically generated barcode (or pkpass file) from the application.

Is such a way even remotely possible? I know it doesn't really conform to "best practice"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the proper way is to get a signed pkpass file from your server to supply to passbook

This is not just the proper way, this is the ONLY way!  Passes cannot be dynamically generated and signed on the device as it would require embedding of your Pass Type ID certificate into your app.

Also, if you are generating and replacing passes with such frequency, the Passbook App will throttle your pass to preserve your users' battery and bandwidth.  This would prevent your pass from updating.

An ugly hack would be to educate users to use the "pull to refresh" function on the back of the pass, then serve a new pass in response to the user request, but this would require a degree of synchronisation between your server, your app and the pass.

Practically, if the barcode is changing every 30 seconds or so, then there is a probability that the barcode expires before the user is able to retrieve the pass and present it for scanning.  Perhaps there is a better way to achieve what you want without such frequent rotation of the barcode?